# Websphere server tutorial

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

Where can I find a good tutorial about complete IBM websphere servers. I need to know the functionality and also details about inbound and outbound ihs also

Comment: From Google Search

Comment: [This](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1208_cheng/1208_cheng.html) is old but a decent overview.  Beyond that, maybe pick some specific parts that you are interested in learning more about and start with the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.5/as_ditamaps/was9_welcome_base.html) and some Google searches.

Comment: You has choice Teacher for instruction IHS. Must choice Teacher for material before and choice link for intruction. As teacher from India is trust for intruction https://www.youtube.com/@Praveen_coaching